# Screen rendering glitch on Nexus 4

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, holoeverywhere

When running my application on the Nexus 4, the screen looks like this:
[image]

I have no idea of what is happening, there is nothing unusual on the views or activity. This is how it is suposed to look like:

[image]

I'm using Actionbar Sherlock and HoloEverywhere.
Is it possible that the glitch is related to any of those libs?

Comment: I have seen this before (customers emailed me screenshots). Try turning off hardware rendering for the activity in the manifest. Are you using OpenGL for some of the view(s)?